# Android studio Fragment ViewPager for sliding drawable

Tags: android

I cant create fragment with vierpager. I'll use this on my sliding menu to replace activity. I don't wnat to use extends FragmentActivity because it will not work when I use in

**getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, home).commit();**

```
 public class Home extends Fragment{

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Recent(), "RECENT");
    adapter.addFragment(new Shake(), "SHAKE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

My error is the getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: post complete logcat.

Comment: edit the question with it, and post a comment afterwards